# leading zeros in jpeg display in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have jpeg saved to file system with either 4 leading zeros or 5 leading zeros, such as this: 0000085.jpeg, or 0000112.jpeg.

But the jpeg is only saved in database with the last numbers, such as 85 or 112,
so when I display the jpeg, I have to either choose 0000 or 00000 so some do not get displayed. I am using:

```
<asp:Image ID="responseImage" runat="server" Width="35px" ImageUrl='<%# IIf(Eval("AvatarPictureID") = "0", "http://ref-ology.com/Content/images/Thumbs/default-avatar_85.jpg", "http://ref-ology.com/Content/Images/Thumbs/0000" + Eval("AvatarPictureID") + "_150.jpeg")%>' />
```

with that image tag, only the 112.jpeg will get displayed because it has 4 zeros.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are saving 0000085 as a number and not a string prior to adding the extension.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your database column is of a string-like data type (`varchar`, `nvarchar`, etc.) instead of a number-like data type (`int`, `bigint`, etc.). You need to store the name as a string in order to preserve the leading zeroes.

Comment: I am using NOPCommerce and it is anything but easy to work with. i am trying to work within their framework and this is how they set it up.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct.  You should be storing the file names in full.  However, this will solve your problem.

```
http://ref-ology.com/Content/Images/Thumbs/" + Eval("AvatarPictureID").ToString("0000000") + "_150.jpeg")%>
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#Y3200

Comment: I tried your help and get this error, System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Sounds like your culture settings are causing a problem. Try the_lotus's answer.  It is basically the same solution and easier to read.

Comment: as i look again, the file is actually saved like this: 0000085_150, 0000120_150, 0000111_150, so that each 7 digit number is followed by _150. I'm sure that makes a difference and why your solution doesn't work. but do you have an idea for this?

Answer (score 1):

What will happen when you'll be in the thousand? I suggest you use the pad function

```
Eval("AvatarPictureID").PadLeft(7, "0")
```

Comment: I get the error, "Public member 'PadLeft' on type 'DBNull' not found." do you know what that means? i did this... "<asp:Image ID="posterImage" runat="server" Width="55px" ImageUrl='<%# IIf(Eval("AvatarPictureID") Is DBNull.Value, "http://ref-ology.com/Content/images/Thumbs/default-avatar_85.jpg", "http://ref-ology.com/Content/Images/Thumbs/" + Eval("AvatarPictureID").PadLeft(7, "0") + "_150.jpeg")%>' />

Comment: It says "PadLeft on DBNull not found". This mean that AvatarPictureID is null and not a string/number. Make sure your query returns all string or number and not null if you want to do it like this.

Comment: some values are null, which is why i am using IIF is DBNull!

Comment: With IIF both side are evaluated no mather what. You can't use IIF for thios purpose. I suggest you create a function, something like: ImageUrl='<%# GetImageFileNameFromID(Eval("AvatarPictureID"))%>'